# Resharper C++ and VSVim clashing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, vsvim

I'm trying to use the Resharper C++ and VSVim together and they seem to clash. When, resharper provides code snippets that can be filled in, I can't go fill in snippets as I can't enter Insert mode by pressing i. If I press Esc, the snippet disappears. This would be an awesome combination if they can play nice together.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you are using the latest VsVim and R# C++ version. I saw the same behavior some time ago but R# C++ 1.1 and VsVim 2.0.1 work well together when a R# hotspot session is active after inserting a template.